# In a finite ring $R$ with identity show that $ab =1$ implies $ba = 1$, where $a,b \in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a finite ring $R$ with identity show that $ab =1$ implies $ba = 1$, where $a,b \in R$.

I am having difficulty in doing this since there is no condition that there is no zero divisors and how will I use the finiteness of the ring!!

Answer (score 0):

If the ring is finite, Let's call n the order of ba.

$$ba = b(ab)a = b(ab(ab))a = b(ab(ab(ab)))a = \cdots = (ba)^n = 1$$

Comment: You seem to preassume that $b$ and $a$ are units. This however is yet to be shown. Why not $b^n=0$ for some $n$?

Comment: Wait, what did I write? -_-'

Comment: @drhab: We can't have $b^n=0$ because $a^nb^n=1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I realize that in this context $b^n=0$ is not possible but still I am wondering: why $a^nb^n=1$? That $(ab)^n=1$ is immediately clear, but the ring is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: @drhab: $a^nb^n=a^{n-1}abb^{n-1}=a^{n-1}b^{n-1}$, and then proceed by induction.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, of course. I am starting to get blind I think. Thank you.

Comment: @Tryss: How do we know that there's any $n>0$ such that $(ba)^n=1$? That's not the case for an arbitrary element in a finite ring, for example in $\mathbb Z_6$ the sequence $2, 2^2, 2^3, \ldots$ never reaches $1$ (nor for that matter $0$).